# How to setup PHPMailer SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send some mail using php mailer, the boring thing is that one email eas sent the first time and I have no idea what I've done that makes this code to now fail.

**ERROR**: SMTP server error: authentication required

```
require("../mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server
$mail->From     = "site email";
$mail->AddAddress("useremail");
$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

I'm hosting with GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jake.

Incase someone goes through this again here is what i put in my code.

**CODE**

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "email@domain";
$mail->Password   = "pwd";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;       
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; /// i guess this is for reporting...  
$mail->From     = "email@domain";
$mail->AddAddress("recipient email");
$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```